# Haskell refer to values in own module

Tags: haskell, module

I am writing a module that basically wraps functionality provided by another module, so there are a several instances of values with the same name imported into the same scope, and I have to disambiguate by prepending the module that I want to use.  I know that I can import the other module under a shorter name (using an `as` clause), but is there any way to reference values in the current module in the same way?  I have tried importing myself qualified, but that causes a cyclic import.

To clarify, I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
module Very.Long.Wrapper.Module.Name (fun) as Self where

import Very.Long.Module.Name.To.Be.Wrapped as M

Self.fun = doSomethingWith M.fun
```

or anything else that will let me do the last line without the entire module name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your import to

```
import qualified Very.Long.Module.Name.To.Be.Wrapped as M
```

Then you will only have to qualify references to M.fun - unqualified `fun` will refer unambiguously to the current module's version.

Comment: Of course; I should have thought of that!  I will accept this answer once the time window passes.